# Canvas: Density Pixels para desenhar imagens

Tags: android, marker

Boa tarde ! 
Estou criando um Marker personalizado para o mapa:

```
        final Bitmap markerIcon = Bitmap.createBitmap(275, 275, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(markerIcon);
```

Estou utilizando tamanhos fixos para as imagens, então dependo da tela do smartphone, o marker fica gigante! 
Gostaria de saber se é possível, e como, usar Density Pixels (dp) no código descrito acima. 
Desde já agradeço a colaboração! 
Saudações,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue como resolvi:

```
 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                 Integer _SizePin = Math.round(  Float.valueOf(100)* metrics.density );
                 Integer _SizePhoto = Math.round(  Float.valueOf(50)* metrics.density );

                final Bitmap markerIcon = Bitmap.createBitmap(_SizePin, _SizePin, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                final Paint paint = new Paint();
                final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(markerIcon);
```